# Dark mode for developer.android.com or any website?

Tags: android, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Is there a way to read [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/packages) in dark mode? Or what is the best chrome/firefox plugin for eye friendly read of android reference?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use google chrome extension [Dark Reader](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh?hl=en-GB&utm_source=ext_sidebar). You can view any website with it in dark mode.